# Every vector bundle has a metric connection?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, connections

Let $(E,g)$ be a vector bundle with a metric over a manifold $M$. Does $(E,g)$ always admit a compatible (metric) connection?

If so, are there examples where there exists only one such metric connection?

Comment: As long as $M$ is paracompact, it's the usual partition of unity argument to define a connection. (Work with an orthonormal basis for sections.) It'll never be unique, even if the bundle is trivial, because you will then have maps $M\to O(n)$ to adjust trivializations by.

Comment: Indeed, the metric connections on $(E,g)$ will always form an affine space modelled on the space of sections of the vector bundle $T^*M\otimes\mathfrak{so}(E)$, where the second factor denotes the bundle of those endomorphisms of $E$ which are skew symmetric with respect to $g$.